How can I rearrange a CSV file with taxonomic data according to to a template list
I am trying to replace the tips of my Phylogenetic tree with the taxa names. I have a CSV file with the tip labels in the first column and the taxa names in the second column. However, the order of the tip labels on the tree is different from the order of the CSV. How can I rearrange the CSV file to match the order of the tip labels without doing it manually?
As expected, this replaces the tip labels in the old tree with data from the CSV and writes it to a new file, but the new tip labels are in the wrong order:
library(ape)
library(phytools)
library(phylotools)
library(evobiR)
library(dplyr)
Tree <- ape::read.tree(file="/Users//AlkBtree.nwk")
List <- read.csv(file="/Users//AlkBStrNames.csv")
tips <- Tree$tip.label
df <- data.frame(List$Name)
dat <- data.frame(tips, df)
ntree <- phylotools::sub.taxa.label(Tree,dat)
ape::write.tree(ntree, file="/Users//AlkBtreeN.nwk")

I tried reordering the list using the evobiR package, but it returned this error:
Reordered <- evobiR::ReorderData(Tree, List$Filename, taxa.names="row names")


Error in new.data[i] <- data[which(names(data) == tree$tip.label[i])] : 
  replacement has length zero

I also other configurations of the same command and got a different but similar error:
> Reordered <- evobiR::ReorderData(Tree, List, taxa.names=2)


Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

Finally, I tried this command:
dats <- match(Tree$tip.label,List)

Which resulted in a list of the correct length but all of the values were "NA"

Try replacing:
df <- data.frame(List$Name)
dat <- data.frame(tips, df)

with:
dat <- List[match(tips, List$Name),]

or, using dplyr:
dat <- left_join(data.frame(tips), List, by = c("tips" = "Name"))


What I’d do would be to reorder the data list to match the tree, and then replace the tip label manually. You can do this just by modifying the list object.
It’s not quite clear to me from your sample code what the name is of each column in List, so I’m going to call them “DataName” for the labels you want and “TreeName” for the labels that are on the tree
So something like:
require(dplyr)
require(ape)
#reorder data to match tree
ordered_list <- List %>%
  arrange(match(TreeName, Tree$tip.label))

Then swap out the tip labels on your tree
Tree$tip.label <- ordered_list$DataName

